# converting times using Chron not working as intended

Tags: r, chron

I have the following vector containing time stamps. These time stamps are recorded as factors.

```
times<-as.factor(c("8:24", "9:17","11:52","1:49","9:36"))
```

I want to convert them in to time objects using the `chron` package. And I have used the following code

```
library(chron)

chron(as.character(times), format = "h:m")
```

however, when I run this it states

```
Error in widths[, fmt$periods, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

how do I get around this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must supply secoonds:

```
times(paste0(times, ":00"))
## [1] 08:24:00 09:17:00 11:52:00 01:49:00 09:36:00
```

These work too:

```
times(c(as.matrix(read.table(text = as.character(times), sep = ":")) %*% c(1, 1/60)/24))
## [1] 08:24:00 09:17:00 11:52:00 01:49:00 09:36:00

times(as.numeric(sub(":.*", "", times)) / 24 + as.numeric(sub(".*:", "", times)) / (24 * 60))
## [1] 08:24:00 09:17:00 11:52:00 01:49:00 09:36:00
```